# Storing Brewed Coffee in a Temperature Controlled Insulated Mug

Tags: storage

Suppose a thermos mug is fully filled with coffee (so there is no air and the coffee can't come in contact with oxygen) and somehow I manage to keep the temperature of coffee around 60 degree to 70 degrees Celsius (140-158 °F) for two days, so I don't need to reheat and as the temperature is higher it can't oxidize with the oxygen of water.

Will the coffee be fresh and taste same after a day or two?

Comment: Hi! I noticed you posted basically the same question twice. According to the site’s rules, we will accept only one and close the other as duplicate. Personally, I think this one is better, but the choice is yours. Next time when you  want to ad more details, note that you can always edit your posts, which would be the best way to do it. I also recommend you take the [tour] and browse through the [help] to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: Oxidation is not the only thing you need to worry about, what about mold?

Comment: Why do you think the higher temperature makes it impossible for the coffee to react with the oxygen in the water?

Comment: because oxidation is heat generating reaction, Higher temperature will make it difficult to generate heat, not impossible though. That will slow the process of oxidation. So, coffee can be fresh for longer time. But can the coffee mold in absence of air?